# jquery, how to create a ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have a function like this:

```
    $("#join").colorbox({
    onComplete:function(){
        // add code here
    },
    width:"530px", height:"500px", inline:true, href:"#add"
});
```

what i would like to do is `onComplete:function()` to create a ajax request to a `xxx.php` file.

i just want to make the request so that i can call a new url. i dont want to load anything from the new file and i dont want to redirect to that file, i just want to make a ajax call to it.

any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "xxx.php",
   success: function(msg){
     alert("Success!");
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the $.ajax function. Like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myurl.php'
});
```

Won't this work?

Answer (score 0):

You would use the [jQuery `$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function.  Since you say you don't want to do anything with the response, you can just have an empty function for the `success` parameter of the `.ajax()` call.  (Though I recommend against doing nothing with the response.  You should at least check that it's good, even if you don't present anything to the user.  *Definitely* don't ignore responses in the `error` parameter.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to send a GET request to your page. It will look like this:

```
$.get('xxx.php');
```

You can use the additional arguments to send data through GET, and to include a callback function if you want to do anything when the request finishes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#join").colorbox({
onComplete:function(){
    $.ajax({
       url: "xxx.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: "param1=value"
       success: function(){
          alert("success");
       }
    });
},
width:"530px", height:"500px", inline:true, href:"#add"
```

you can reference jquery's .ajax() method.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

If that is all you need, just do a $.get("xxx.php"); in you onComplete function.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.get`
If you want to send anything to this page send in the second param

```
$.get("xxx.php", {});
```